# How do I add an admin page with Kohana?

Tags: php, controller, frameworks, kohana, kohana-3.3

I'm new to Kohana (inherited an older project). I'm trying to add an admin page by copying how other admin listing pages have been done like this in application/bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('admin_jobusers', 'admin#/jobusers(/<action>(/<id>(/<slug>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'admin_jobusers',
    'action'     => 'index'
));
```

I have a controller, similar to others in the project, and have added a link in the navigation mimicking existing links like this:

```
echo URL::site('admin#/jobusers');
```

However, without the # in the URL I can get the page to show some output, though without any theming. All other links created this way work fine. With the # in the URL it simply redirects me to the default admin page.

My question is:

- What is the # in the URL and how is it used?
- What am I missing here? How can I get the controller to display the content within the themed page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not kohana problem, read about url hash. you cant get it in php, but you can do it in js: create click handler and send ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I found that it is being controlled by js in the theme.